# Mapping dynamically created elements with xml elements

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

My android app supposed to have a `LinearLayout` contained in a `HorizontalScrollView`, now i have to declare a number of another contained layouts that are contained in that main layout but i don't know the number or the data of these layouts as I take this data from the server i connect to after the app launching, So, the main layout that contained in the HorizontalScrollView is created in the XML file and it's contained layouts must created throw run time by the java code. So, i take them from the server database and put them in a two-dimentional array and then make a loop to loop throw that array and create a layouts equal to that array size, I don't know if this way is right or not but it gives me nothing, and this is my code :

**XML:**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ver1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rooms"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_rooms"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ver_rooms"
           android:baselineAligned="false"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">


        </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA:**(`Rooms` is the `Array` that contains the layout data)

```
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homeview, null);

            LinearLayout ver_rooms = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ver_rooms);
            List<LinearLayout> inner_ver = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_ineer_ver = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_icon = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                      0, 1);
            lp_icon.setMargins(10, 15, 5, 0);

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels/4, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.setMargins(10, 15, 5, 0);


            for(int i = 0 ; i < (Integer)((Rooms.size()/2)+1) ; i++){
                inner_ver.add(new LinearLayout(this));
                inner_ver.get(i).setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
                inner_ver.get(i).setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                inner_ver.get(i).setWeightSum(2);
                inner_ver.get(i).setPadding(7, 7, 7, 7);
                ver_rooms.addView(inner_ver.get(i));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

im having trouble figuring out where you are adding the images to the layouts, besides that, you are adding a new lienarLayour, but you dont keep any reference to it, so you wont be able to add anything to it.

Comment: that's also another thing i asking about, can the array index be a reference to the layout? i mean can I deal with it like 'inner_ver.get(i)' ?

Comment: oh sorry, i got that wrong, you are filling a list with the layouts to keep a reference, that should work fine. but you are adding an empty linear layout.
but im curious, why dont you use a listview?

Comment: I planned to add an empty LinearLayout so i add it's elements later, and I didn't think about using a ListView as i don't use it before, you think it will be helpful here ?

Comment: well, you are basically trying to build a listview yourself. but somebody already did that work for you. Your images are in a db you filled? use cursor adapter to pull your images from db and display them in a listview, it doesnt need to know how many will be there.